# cannot join the tables properly. infinite time taken by query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, sqlperformance

I am facing performance issues with my sqlcode. Using Tableau platform

I have around 11 joins of tables. when I debug to see the performance of the 10 joined tables, its very fast in tableau but when i add one more table of `billing_transaction`, the query is never ending even with a small set of rows.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6FB0RrT5sGIdWR2T25YeE1tSTA/view?usp=sharing) is the ERD of the whole database. What could be the problem that its creating an long query?

Here is the SQL code (I have commented out the FROM section without the table billing_transaction, was doing it for comparing the performance)

```
select 
    country.`name` as Country,
    oper.`name` as Operator,
    proj.`name` as Project,
    club.`name` as Club,
    prom.`name` as Promotor,
    cust.`idCustomer` as SubscriberID,
    cust_sub.`msisdn` as SubscriberMsidn,
    cust.`customerSince` as SubscriberStartingDate,
    cust_sub.`SubscribedDate` as SubscriberSubcribeDate,
    cust_sub.`UnsubscribedDate` as SubscriberUnSubcribeDate,
    cust_sub.`idCustomerSubscription` as SubscriptionID,
    bt.`idBillingTransaction` as BillingTransactionID,
    cust_sub.`eventId` as SubscriberEventID,
    bt_status.`name` as BillingStatus,
    bt.`price` as Pricefromsubscriber



-- FROM `customersubscription` cust_sub (WITHOUT billing_transaction it WORKS FINE)
--  LEFT JOIN `customer` cust on cust_sub.`idCustomer`=cust.`IdCustomer`
--  LEFT JOIN `promoter` prom on cust_sub.`idPromoter`=prom.`id`
--  LEFT JOIN `club` club on cust_sub.`idClub`=club.`idClub`
--  LEFT JOIN `Project` proj on club.`idProject`=Proj.`idProject`
--  LEFT JOIN `project_operator_relationships` proj_rel_oper on proj.`idProject`=proj_rel_oper.`projectId`
--  LEFT JOIN `Operator` as oper on proj_rel_oper.`operatorId`=oper.`idOperator`
--  LEFT JOIN `country` as country on oper.`idCountry`=country.`idCountry`
--  LEFT JOIN `curreny_symbol` as curr_sym on country.`idCurrencySymbol`=curr_sym.`symbol`,


FROM `billing_transaction` bt
    LEFT JOIN `customersubscription` cust_sub on bt.`msisdn`=cust_sub.`msisdn`
    LEFT JOIN `customer` cust on cust.`idCustomer`=cust_sub.`IdCustomer`
    LEFT JOIN `billing_status` bt_status on bt.`idBillingStatus`=bt_status.`idBillingStatus`
    LEFT JOIN `promoter` prom on cust_sub.`idPromoter`=prom.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `club` club on cust_sub.`idClub`=club.`idClub`
    LEFT JOIN `Project` proj on club.`idProject`=Proj.`idProject`
    LEFT JOIN `project_operator_relationships` proj_rel_oper on proj.`idProject`=proj_rel_oper.`projectId`
    LEFT JOIN `Operator` as oper on proj_rel_oper.`operatorId`=oper.`idOperator`
    LEFT JOIN `country` as country on oper.`idCountry`=country.`idCountry`
    LEFT JOIN `curreny_symbol` as curr_sym on country.`idCurrencySymbol`=curr_sym.`symbol`

where proj.`idProject` IN (3, 19)
-- where proj.`idProject` IN (3, 19, 23, 24, 27)
    and date(cust_sub.`SubscribedDate`)>='2017-04-18 01:40:00'
    and date(cust_sub.`SubscribedDate`)< '2017-04-18 02:00:00'
```

Any suggestions will be very much appreciated. Debug all but I dont know where is the performance issues. I cannot ignore the table as well

my approach (which can be wrong as i m new to it) is that, taking the billing_transaction tables, keep left joining and adding up the information in the next columns of the rows like customer subscription, customers, operator, club, project.... all the way to country. The left join is suitable for such scenario? Also, does the where clause matters to be from the billing_transaction (main table) or where clause can be from any table in the joining tables.

The sequence goes like this

```
Each customer has one or more subscription
Each Subscription has one or more billing transaction
Each billing transaction has one or more billing status


Other relations are:
Each customer subscription have one or more club
Each customer subscription has one or more promotor
Each club has one or more project
Each project has one or more operator
Each operator has one or more countries
Each country has one or more currency
```

Comment: suggest create a fiddle so we can play around

Comment: fiddle meaning?

Comment: sqlfiddle.com so you can create your schema

Comment: data source is from remote server. will fiddle work?

Comment: you have to create your schema there.

Comment: Do you have indexes on all of the columns used in the various join clauses? Are any of these columns a type _other than_ __int__? If you left off the where clause, roughly how many rows would be returned?

Comment: some of them are varchar, very few are decimal

Comment: i narrowed down the rows by making the date range very short

Comment: so it would be around 400 500 rows i believe

Comment: From your edit it seems that you need to do some studying in the different form of JOINs. No, LEFT JOIN is not suitable for this scenario, but now the question has become too broad and it needs to be narrowed down again. So try to resolve your original problem first, and then please study JOINs, they are a ubiquitous part of SQL.

Comment: And by the way from your explanations it seems that only INNER JOINs are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Change the left join in

```
SELECT ...
FROM `billing_transaction` bt
    LEFT JOIN `customersubscription` cust_sub on bt.`msisdn`=cust_sub.`msisdn`
    ...
```

to an inner join:

```
SELECT ...
FROM `billing_transaction` bt
    JOIN `customersubscription` cust_sub on bt.`msisdn`=cust_sub.`msisdn`
    ...
```

You are left joining a potentially huge table (`billing_trnsaction`) on which you have applied **no filter** at all. But what is the point of a `left join` here? Can there be a billing transaction without customer?

Likewise, **review all your LEFT JOINS** and replace them with INNER JOINS if possible. Then apply filters appropriately (when possible where an index exists).

Comment: I am not sure which one to inner join and which one to left join.

Comment: For starters please try my suggestion (replace the first LEFT JOIN with JOIN) and let us know how it goes.

Comment: @PythonDev any news?